# Does OpenMP hints bypass the vectorisation legality check in llvm

Tags: clang, llvm, openmp, vectorization

I am currently looking into how "#pragma omp for simd" is actually recognised in llvm. To my knowledge, clang will parse it and set metadata in IR to indicate this force-vectorisation hint and later optimisation passes would read it and vectorise the marked loop. Therefore, the loop should be vectorised even the compiler think it might not be safe to do so?

So my assumption is that such force-vectorisation hints should bypass both the vectorisation legality and cost model check. However, in LoopVectorize.cpp, I can't see how this is done. All loops will be sent to a legality check of LVL.canVectorize() and, if this condition does not fit, it return to false directly without actually reaching the vectorisation stage.

Is there anything wrong with my assumption made on the use of force-vectorisation hints?

Thanks in advance,
T

Comment: Could be an interesting question. It would be nice to see some code though.

Answer (score 0):

While llvm has publicized a goal of going beyond gcc in implementation of omp simd, I haven't seen much of that myself.  I don't see any updates of their high level docs in last 2 years. While it might be loosely described as "vectorize if you know how," I don't think anyone considers it as overriding proved dependencies. I wouldn't be surprised if it acts like auto vectorization with cost model suspended and possible but unproven dependencies ignored.